# make[1]: *** /lib/modules//build/: No such file or directory. Stop

Tags: makefile, module, linux-kernel, kernel-module, archlinux

i was compiling a kernel module **thermal.c** at an **ARCH linux distro** using **Makefile**

Makefile:

```
obj-m += thermal.o

all:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build/ M=$(PWD) modules

clean:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build/ M=$(PWD) clean
```

the make command output is:

```
make -C /lib/modules//build/ M=/home/user/dir modules
make[1]: *** /lib/modules//build/: No such file or directory.  Stop.
make: *** [Makefile:4: all] Error 2
```

`uname -r` output : **5.6.8-arch1-1**

Answer (score 2):

make expands the recipes before passing them to the shell. In your case make replaced `$(PWD)` by the value of the make variable named `PWD` (correct) but it also replaced `$(uname -r)` by the value of the make variable named `uname -r`. As there was no such make variable defined, the result was the empty string. Using `$$(uname -r)` solves the problem because make expands it as `$(uname -r)`, exactly what you want to pass to the shell.

In summary, you must escape the `$` you want to preserve from the make expansion by doubling them:

```
all:
    make -C /lib/modules/$$(uname -r)/build/ M=$(PWD) modules

clean:
    make -C /lib/modules/$$(uname -r)/build/ M=$(PWD) clean
```

Comment: Or one may use `\`uname -r\`` variant.

Comment: ls -al /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build/
ls: cannot access '/lib/modules/5.0.2-aml-s905/build/': No such file or directory

Comment: @CSQGB So you don't have a directory `/lib/modules/5.0.2-aml-s905/build/`. Should you have one? If the answer is "no" everything is fine. If it is "yes" you need to understand why this directory is not there.

Comment: apt can not search linux-headers-5.0.2, can I use `linux-headers-5.0.0-65-generic` to replace?

Comment: Please ask a real new question with enough details for somebody to answer. Explain what you're trying to do, what's wrong, etc. You can also visit the help center and especially [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).